# Why the client (HoloLens by C#) cannnot receive message form the server (PC by python)? ( The client can send images to the server.)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

Here is part of the scripts of the Client (HoloLens). I use ReceiveMessage() to receive the data sent from the server, but actually I cannot receive anything. SendImage(byte[] image) can send images from the client to the server and works very well. Why? Is there anything wrong with ReceiveMessage()?
After I get the string data (name form python), I want to use the result of ReceiveMessage() to assign a value to an object's text to display on HoloLens.
'''

```
using System;
#if UNITY_UWP
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
#endif

public class TcpNetworkClientManager
{
    public static string Name = "";
#if UNITY_UWP    
    private Stream stream = null;
    private StreamWriter writer = null;
    private StreamReader reader = null;


#endif

    public TcpNetworkClientManager(string IP, int port)
    {
#if UNITY_UWP
        Task.Run(async () => {
            StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket();            
            await socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName(IP),port.ToString());
            stream = socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
            writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead());        
            writer = null;
   
        
        });
#endif
    }

    public void SendMessage(string data)
    {
#if UNITY_UWP
        if (writer != null) Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await writer.WriteAsync(data);
            await writer.FlushAsync();
        });
#endif
    }

    public void SendImage(byte[] image)
    {
#if UNITY_UWP
        if (stream != null) Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(image, 0, image.Length);
            await stream.FlushAsync();
        });
#endif
    }

    public void ReceiveMessage()
    {
#if UNITY_UWP
        
        if (reader != null) Task.Run(async () =>
        {              
            try
            {
                string message = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                Name = message;
            }
            catch (Exception) { }  

           
                
        });
#endif
    }
}
```

'''
Here is the script of the GameObject named client. It is the most important part to realize the function in Unity.
'''

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.XR.WSA.WebCam;
using HoloToolkit.Unity.InputModule;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Client: MonoBehaviour, IInputClickHandler
{

    public string IP;
    public int port;
    public Text connectButtonText;
    public TextMesh debugText;

    private PhotoCapture photoCaptureObject = null;
    private Texture2D targetTexture = null;
    private Resolution cameraResolution;

    private TcpNetworkClientManager client = null;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
        //debugText.text = cameraResolution.width.ToString() + " " + cameraResolution.height.ToString();
        targetTexture = new Texture2D(cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height);
        // targetTexture = new Texture2D(480, 270);
        // InputManager.Instance.PushFallbackInputHandler(gameObject);
        InputManager.Instance.AddGlobalListener(gameObject);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (client!=null)
        {
            client.ReceiveMessage();
            debugText.text = TcpNetworkClientManager.Name;
        }
    }

    void OnStoppedPhotoMode(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
    {
        photoCaptureObject.Dispose();
        photoCaptureObject = null;
    }

    void OnCapturedPhotoToMemory(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result, PhotoCaptureFrame photoCaptureFrame)
    {
        photoCaptureFrame.UploadImageDataToTexture(targetTexture);
        //byte[] texByte = targetTexture.EncodeToJPG();
        //byte[] image = new byte[texByte.Length];
        //Array.Copy(texByte, image, texByte.Length);

        byte[] image = targetTexture.GetRawTextureData();
        client.SendImage(image);
        photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
    }

    public void OnInputClicked(InputClickedEventData eventData)
    {
        if (client != null)
        {
            PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(true, delegate (PhotoCapture captureObject)
            {
                photoCaptureObject = captureObject;
                CameraParameters cameraParameters = new CameraParameters();
                cameraParameters.hologramOpacity = 0.9f;
                cameraParameters.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
                cameraParameters.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
                cameraParameters.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;
                photoCaptureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(cameraParameters, delegate (PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
                {
                    photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
                });
            });
        }
    }

    public void ConnectButtonClicked()
    {
        if(client != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Disconnected");
            connectButtonText.text = "Connect";
            client = null;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Connected");
            client = new TcpNetworkClientManager(IP, port);
            connectButtonText.text = "Disconnect";
        }
    }
}
```

'''

Here is part of the scripts of the server (PC). I use clientsock.sendall(name.encode()) to send the data of name (Python receives the image from HoloLens and then process the image to get the name of people in the image) from server to client.
'''

```
def main():
    host = "10.24.82.21"
    port = 8000

    width = 2048
    height = 1152

    serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    serversock.bind((host,port))
    serversock.listen(10)

    print('Waiting for connections...')
    clientsock, client_address = serversock.accept()
    
    print("Succeeded in Connection!")
    
    total = 0
    buffer_size = 4*width*height
    while True:
        data = b''
        data = clientsock.recv(buffer_size)
        print(len(data))
        if len(data) == buffer_size:
            tmp = np.frombuffer(data, np.uint8, -1)
            img = tmp.reshape(height, width, 4)            
            #img = cv2.resize(img, (480, 270))
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            img = cv2.flip(img, 0)
            
            #cv2.imshow("img", img)
            #cv2.waitKey(1000)
            #LoadImages(data)
            name = FaceRec(img) #recognize the img and return the name
            print (name)
            clientsock.sendall(name.encode())
            print ("this is " + name)
            
            
            #cv2.imwrite("out.jpg", img)
            #cv2.waitKey(3000)
            #cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            #break
    clientsock.close()
```

'''

Comment: It seems that the code you have posted running on HoloLens should work. And it should have nothing to do with the network. Could you double-check that the `FaceRec(img)` function invoked in your python script returns a valid name string?

Comment: Actually the FaceRec(img) can work very well if I don't use the method of ReceiveMessage(). I don't know how to call this method of ReceiveMessage() in another script. I'm trying to use
message=new TcpNetworkClientManager(IP,port),
And then make
Text = message.ReceiveMessage()
and putting it into the void update() function
This doesn't seem to work. It's going to crash the whole socket.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the ReceiveMessage method is invoked before the asynchronous task assinge the, I made some modifications on your code, you can programmatically store this in your project:

```
public TcpNetworkClientManager(string IP, int port)
{
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
    Connect(IP, port);
#endif
}

#if !UNITY_EDITOR

public async void Connect(string IP, int port)
{
    try
    {
        StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket();
        await socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName(IP), port.ToString());

        Stream streamOut = socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
        writer = new StreamWriter(streamOut) { AutoFlush = true };

        Stream streamIn = socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
        reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);
        ReceiveMessage();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But when I try to put it into the whole script, I get the exception from Unity "Feature `asynchronous functions' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification". The unity version is 2017.4.1. How can I cope with it? Thank you again!

Comment: According to the error message, it should put the whole async function in the conditional compilation statement body. I have fixed that in the code. If it still cannot work after trying this, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: BTW,  for Unity 2017, the minimum supported version is 2017.4.17, you should use this version or above: https://unity3d.com/unity/whatsnew/unity-2017.4.17

Comment: Thank you so much for your great script! To be more specific, I have added the other script of the game object named Client to the question. There are two things to realize. 1. The game object named client can capture the image and call the method "SendImage(byte[] image)" to send it to PC. And it works.  2. I want to get string data sent back from PC and show it on a text. But it doesn't work. Actually I don't know how to let the game object named client call the corresponding method (ReceiveMessage()) to let the text show the string data. If possible, could you give me some suggestions?

Comment: In my code, it has been invoked after the socket connected to a remote network, and only invoked it once. From your code, you should make sure the socket.ConnectAsync has returned and there is no need to put ReceiveMessage() into the update() function, just call it once to receive the data from your python server.